# Angular, problema en anidación de componentes

Tags: javascript, angular, component

Tengo un problema al anidar un componente dentro de `app.componen.html`, ya que logro con *ViewContainerRef* y *ComponentFactoryResolver* que lo anide al pulsar un botón y eliminarlo con otro botón con `ngOnDestroy()`

La cuestión es que quiero cerrar dicho componente(`publication.component`) con un botón integrado dentro de dicho componente y no con uno externo de `app.component`

Si no es posible, ¿cúal sería la mejor forma de realizar estas acciones?
Gracias de antemano

```
<div class="publicar">

<button *ngFor='let tab of tabs' class="publicar_boton" (click)='chargeComponent($event)'>
    <img src="assets/iconos/407-twitter.png">
</button>

<button *ngIf='pos != 0' (click)='ngOnDestroy()' class="publicar_boton_cerrar">
    Cerrar externo
</button>
```

```js
  public pos: number = 0;
  @ViewChild('ref', {read: ViewContainerRef}) ref;
  chargeComponent() {
      if(this.pos == 0) {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.tabs[0].component);
    this.ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    this.ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.pos = 1;
      }
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.pos = 0;
      this.ref.destroy();
      this.ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, [el código debe ir como texto, no como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-código-vale-más-que-mil-imágenes-cómo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Ya está, lo siento aun no me manejo en este sitio